# ASP.NET Core публикация на Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net, postgresql, asp

Работаю над проектом ASP.NET Core. Решил опубликовать на Linux VPS. Установив dotnet и nginx на linux, проект опубликовать получилось. Но! Не подключается к базе данных PostgreSQL. Выдает ошибку:

> fail: Vue2Spa.Program[0]
> An error occurred while seeding the database.
> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallS iteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

Подключаюсь так:

**appsettings.json**

```
Host=**.**.**.**;Port=5432;Database=***;Username=postgres;Password=****
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["connectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
```

Вроде говорит, что не хватает памяти. Но ОЗУ 1ГБ, жесткий - 20 Гб. Даже для базы данных со 100 строк кода это много, думаю. Пробовал убрать подключение по паролю. Но не дало результатов.
Подключение к SQL Server проходит успешно. Но к PostgreSQL не подключается.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите в любом системном мониторе, кто и сколько занимает памяти, наверное?

Comment: В линуксе не силен. Как я могу просмотреть это? Т.е. как я могу получить список процессов и посмотреть что грузит ОЗУ и.т.д.?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Например через htop

Comment: Ошибка исправлена добавлением еще 1 ГБ ОЗУ. Но появилась следующая ошибка  Vue2Spa.Program[0]
      An error occurred while seeding the database.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream

Comment: Если у вас возникли новые вопросы, то не пишите их в комментариях. Либо отредактируйте этот вопрос, нажав ссылку "Править", либо создайте новую тему.